# display convert_tz results as desired time format

Tags: mysql

I'm using a session time in a query to convert the results of my query to the desired timezone on the fly:

```
CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(cal_events.event_start), @@session.time_zone, '+11:00') as "Time"
```

This gives me output like this:
2017-10-07 13:00:00

But I'd like to try and get %r output - eg:
1:00:00 PM

Can't figure out how to do that in my statement - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `DATE_FORMAT` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

`DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(cal_events.event_start), @@session.time_zone, '+11:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i:%s %p') as "Time"`

The key is the formatting `%Y-%m-%d %l:%i:%s %p`, specifically `%p` gives you AM/PM and `%l` gives you the 12 hour time format

Comment: Terrific! Thanks very much for your help @Aknosis